# How can I see the last 200 referrals in a Drupal 7 website?

Tags: 7

I'd like to be able to see where the last 200 (or so) visitors to my drupal site came from. I understand that the global HTTP_REFERER variable is what I'll need, but I'm not sure how to proceed. I don't see a global variable in the API docs to help me with this. Any ideas?

If there is an existing module (surprising the me that I can't find one) that provides this functionality, I'm all ears. I have already set up google analytics, and I can see referrals from the GA dashboard. However, GA seems to aggregate referrals (it tells me that I had 1000 referrals from Facebook over the life of my site, for instance), whereas I want to see the specific referral for each visitor.

Comment: Drupal core has a statistics module, but I'm not sure if it supports this. But why don't you use GA, Pikwik, ...

Comment: Thanks Attiks. You're right, I should just use google analytics. And there is even a very nice google_analytics_reports module that provides some nice views-based results.